# Override Net Unit Price via Price Rule in Salesforce CPQ?

Tags: cpq, pricing

I have the fields setup to support the standard functionality to override either the net unit price or the net total price, but I can't seem to figure out how to use this when trying to override via a price rule as it doesn't seem that any fields store the information in any standard way.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: what do you mean by "  how to use this when trying to override via a price rule as it doesn't seem that any fields store the information in any standard way"

Comment: is your price rule not overwriting prices from standard price book?

Comment: @nightcrawler The issue is that we have price rules that calculate the current price, and then that is changed any additional discounts applied, and if that price ends in an amount of change, we want to round that down to the nearest dollar. So I would need to overwrite a price and have it not take into account the current discount percent that is applied to all of our products.

Comment: In your line editor field set, did you add special price?you can override price in that field

Comment: @nightcrawler so I looked up the field to see if that would work, and it looks like it's there but I can't add it to the line editor field set. Any suggestions?

Comment: I dont see any reason why you cant add except for nunber of columns. Try removing some other fields and add special price. If that works, then you need to decide what fields you want to show on line editor

Comment: @nightcrawler I tried removing some fields, and it still didn't show as an available field in the selection. I created a support case, and the agent I worked with said it is not something available to the field sets currently, and that it would need to be added by a dev in the next update to the CPQ.